# How are new franchisee fees in IPL decided?

Tags: cricket, indian-premier-league

When the Indian Premier League was started in 2008, bids were given for 10 yrs for every franchise. I have not heard anything about new bids submitted by the existing franchisees. How much money should the franchisees pay now to the BCCI ? Weren't the existing contracts expired ?